# sphinx не ищет комбинацию текста и числа

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

На сайте прикручен sphinx. Но при выполнении поиска "Пользователь 1" выдает пустой результат. Если убрать число из запроса, то находит пользователей. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы заработал такой поиск, можно сделать небольшой хак и дописать в конфиг `expand_keywords = 1`.

expand_keywords
Автоматически расширяет поисковый запрос до трех запросов

running -> ( running | *running* | =running )

Просто слово с морфологией, слово со звездочками и полное совпадение слова. Раньше этой опции не было и чтобы поискать со звездочками мне приходилось вручную делать дополнительный запрос, сейчас все включается одной опцией. Так же автоматом полное совпадение будет в поисковой выдаче выше.

К тому же, нужно обратить внимание на "точность" работы поиска. А именно показатель [min_infix_len](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len). у меня его значение в конфиге напрямую ограничивает минимальное количество распознаваемых цифр в запросе.

Нашел на хабре отличную статью на тему [sphinx](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147745/). Ну и, конечно, [документация](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-expand-keywords) на эту тему.